# Reduce density matrix for given eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information

My question is about how to find reduce density matrix for partition of given eigenfunction. Full question is just in image.

[image]

Comment: What does your book say about determining a density matrix?

Comment: This is complete question...i have been asked to find the composite matrix for '0 to L ' then reduce density matrix for part A and for part B  then entanglement b/w two partition..and moreover partition is not at L/2 ...it might be at any point in length L.

Comment: I understand what your question is asking, what *I'm asking* is what does your *book* say about the density matrix of a given $|\psi_n\rangle$ (i.e., what is the *equation* for it?).

Comment: See the Physics SE [homework policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange/715#715). It's not enough to just state the question.